# implement vlookup like function in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting

I have an object in my React component's state that looks like this:

```
const elementPositions =  {
  "0": 180.2,
  "1": 350.8666666666667,
  "2": 521.5333333333333,
  "3": 692.2,
  "4": 862.8666666666667,
  "5": 1033.5333333333333,
  "6": 1204.2
}
```

I have scroll listener that returns a scroll position value, let's say `const scrollY = 466` in this instance.

I need to create a function that returns the corresponding index for the scroll position - i.e. `466` would return 1 since it is greater than `350` but less than `521`. What's the best way to achieve this? I was thinking something along the lines of this but am not sure it's the best approach:

```
const values = Object.values(elementPositions)
values.push(scrollY)
values.sort((a, b) => {return a-b})
const newIndex = values.indexOf(scrollY) - 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your numbers seem to be increments of about 170, so you should be able to do it with arithmetic in constant time (no sorting, loops, etc).

```js
const elementPositions =  {
  "0": 180.2,
  "1": 350.8666666666667,
  "2": 521.5333333333333,
  "3": 692.2,
  "4": 862.8666666666667,
  "5": 1033.5333333333333,
  "6": 1204.2
};

function getPos(x) {
  return elementPositions[Math.floor((x-180.2) / 170.66666666666)] || 0;
}

// test
for (const n of [0,10,180,181,350,351,466,521,522,692,693,862,863,1033,1034,1204,1205]) {
  console.log(n, getPos(n));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `elementPositions` is an array:

```
[180.2, 350.866, ...]
```

This will return the value in `O(n)` (better than sorting):

```
// Get all values smaller than current scrollY
positions = elementPositions.filter(e => e <= scrollY);

// The last element will be the one closest
value = positions.length ? positions[positions.length - 1] : elementPositions[0];
```

You can then use `.indexOf` to get the index if you want.

By no means this is considered efficient, and you should not do this on every scroll event.

The most efficient way is probably doing a binary search which is `O(log n)`:

```js
function rec_search(array, value, left, right) {
    if (right - left == 1) return left;
    var middle = Math.floor((left + right) / 2),
        middleValue = array[middle];
    if (value < middleValue) return rec_search(array, value, left, middle);
    else return rec_search(array, value, middle, right);
}

function search(array, value) {
    if (array.length == 0) return -1;
    if (value < array[0]) return -1;
    if (value > array[array.length - 1]) return array.length - 1;
    return rec_search(array, value, 0, array.length - 1);
}

var positions = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32];  // sorted array
console.log(search(positions, 7));
```

You can also compute an index algebraically if you know the function that generated the numbers.